# SSIS - one data file from two data sources

Tags: ssis, datasource, flat-file

Is it possible to write data from two data sources to a single flat file, with only one data flow?

I have a process with three data flows -

1. Run SP for its record count.
2. Write dates and record count to flat file.
3. Run SP again and write data to the flat file.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Is the data from sources complementary? Or does it have the same structure, which you want to put row by row, source by source in file?

Comment: the sources are identical but provide different columns and data.  The first source is for row count of stored procedure and the start/stop dates; these values are written as first line of the text file.  The second source is the data set returned from the same stored procedure.